# PL/SQL Function result to a table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I currently have a function which is returning a refcursor. I would like to  store the results of this function into a table (Maybe a temp table) and join these results with another table using on a column (IVC_CODE).

```
CREATE FUNCTION EMP_REFCURSOR_F
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
  v_plan_name plans.plan_name%type;
  v_comp_name companies.comp_name%type;
  v_comp_code companies.comp_code%type;
BEGIN
  RETURN rr400_generate_sip_movement.get_sip_movement(
           137610,
           v_plan_name,
           v_comp_name,
           v_comp_code
         );
END;
```

Apologies in advance. Hope I have framed my question correctly. I am really new to PL/SQL. Also I am using SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is (more or less) what you have and what you should do to store result returned by function into a table.

Function (I didn't feel like creating yet another one which returns refcursor to it):

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    retval sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open retval for
  7    select deptno, dname, loc
  8    from dept;
  9
 10    return retval;
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.
```

Target table:

```
SQL> create table temp_rc as select deptno, dname, loc from dept where 1 = 2;

Table created.

SQL> select * from temp_rc;

no rows selected
```

Code which retrieves data from function and stores it into a table:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_deptno dept.deptno%type;
  3    l_dname  dept.dname%type;
  4    l_loc    dept.loc%type;
  5    rc       sys_refcursor;
  6  begin
  7    rc := f_test;
  8    loop
  9      fetch rc into l_deptno, l_dname, l_loc;
 10      exit when rc%notfound;
 11      insert into temp_rc (deptno, dname, loc)
 12        values (l_deptno, l_dname, l_loc);
 13    end loop;
 14    close rc;
 15  end;
 16  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from temp_rc;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL> truncate table temp_Rc;

Table truncated.
```

---

So, yes - it works. Once again: from my point of view, this is what you should do: use function's lines #7 and 8 **only**:

```
SQL> insert into temp_rc (deptno, dname, loc)
  2    select deptno, dname, loc
  3    from dept;

4 rows created.

SQL> select * from temp_rc;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

---

Your code probably isn't that simple, but principle should be just the same - if possible, use code that is behind `rr400_generate_sip_movement.get_sip_movement` and insert data directly into a table. If that's not possible (maybe that function is very complex), well ... now you know how to do it.

Comment: Thank you @littlefoot. You are right in saying I must get my results directly from my package function. I have put another question for this, thank you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75722216/pl-sql-join-package-functions-results-with-another-select-statement-results

Comment: Just a quick question what is 'dept' here. Is it another table which exists in the database? When you creating temp_rc why do we have to use "select deptno, dname, loc from dept where 1 = 2;"

Comment: **DEPT** is table in Scott's sample schema (it was part of Oracle database for many releases; EMP (employees) and DEPT (departments) are probably the most known & popular tables for Oracle users). As of **CTAS** (Create Table As Select) I used: it created structure that looks exactly as the DEPT table, but it is empty because 1 = 2 is never true so that SELECT doesn't return any rows.